# Invalid android_key parameter in facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have got the hash key from my debug store using

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\user.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e

and pasted the key to Facebook App for Android and also enabled "Facebook Login" option.

When I first time log into my Android App, it shows me a permission dialog and after giving the permission, I am enable to get me details from Facebook.

But after that when i exit and the app and again open and try to login, it shows the Error page that is " Invalid android_key_parameter. The key XXXXXXXXX doest not match any allowed key. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/1426974990884277"

I don't get this, if hash key is the issues, then why it works in first attempt.

Comment: when you fire the above command. Had it ask for password or not?

Comment: Please add additional information to your problem in order for others to check whether your code has some issues.  You are stating that your program operates correctly (the first time) but we do not know whether the entry code for the second time is correct. So without code it could be anything and it is hard to analyze.